# Finding Qt with CMake: Missing moc, uic, rcc

Tags: windows, qt, qt4, cmake

I'm trying to fix the installation of a custom built Qt. I'm using the `qt.conf` from [this very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511370/how-to-include-a-certain-qt-installation-using-cmake). However, CMake 2.8.7 is still unable to find moc, uic, and rcc.

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:97 (MESSAGE):
  Could NOT find Qt4 (missing: QT_MOC_EXECUTABLE QT_RCC_EXECUTABLE
  QT_UIC_EXECUTABLE) (found suitable exact version "4.8.1")
```

I have manually set the `QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE` variable to the correct value, namely `B:/lib/vs10/Qt-4.8.1-VS10x64/bin/qmake.exe`. After deploying the `qt.conf` file, `qmake -v` returns the correct path:

```
c:\>B:/lib/vs10/Qt-4.8.1-VS10x64/bin/qmake.exe -v
QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.8.1 in B:/lib/vs10/Qt-4.8.1-VS10x64/lib
```

`qmake -query QT_INSTALL_PREFIX` also returns the correct path. Note that I can't use environment variables because we need different Qt versions for different projects.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You should set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to `B:/lib/vs10/Qt-4.8.1-VS10x64/bin` instead of setting `QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE`. It will help cmake to find all qt executables.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that they decided to make `QT_BINARY_DIR` a `CACHE INTERNAL` variable, which wasn't reset properly after changing `qt.conf` and deleting the `QT_*` variables in CMake. `QT_BINARY_DIR` is only reset if the path of the `qmake.exe` changes. After clearing the cache it worked.

The lessons I draw from this: Don't use `CACHE INTERNAL`, just `FORCE` and `mark_as_advanced`.